# Can’t clean install High Sierra on my mac

Tags: macos, high-sierra, usb

After downgrading to El capitan to test if my MBP mid-2010 would be faster ( which proved to be not significantly so), I decided to upgrade again to High Sierra, but I have found out that I cannot use my earlier downloaded High Sierra Installer to clean install it through a USB stick.

The createinstallmedia works, but I get failure when I run the installer.

When I removing the installinfo.plist file I get “This copy of the Install macOS High Sierra.app application is damaged and can't be used to install macOS”

The only solution is to upgrade it through a 20Mb installer from app store. Still, I am puzzled as how to do a USB clean install. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get when you run the create install media script from your existing package?

Comment: I don’t get any errors when creating the install media, it is only when I want to install the OS on my drive that it refuses to initiate the installation procedure and gives the above error.

Comment: Oh, is there a /var/log/install.log left on the drive(s). It might have more details

Comment: Of course eventually you’re just gonna have to download a new installer but it might be interesting to know what the photo is. I was assuming create install media would recheck the certificates and give you a better error message

Comment: The last line of install.log reads: NSSoftLinking - The Quartz framework’s library could’t be loaded from /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.franework/Cersions/A/Quartz

Comment: InstallAssistant [618:52746] NSColorlist could not parse color list file /System/Library/Colors/System.clr

Comment: InstallAssistant [618:52746] Failed to connect (continuepane) outlet from (IASetupWindowController) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable